# How to handle a content ranking system?

Tags: database, rest, websocket

I know the question is worded very badly, so I'll give an example.

Let's say we have a filesystem that stores hundreds of files, and a database with paths to these files.
Each stored  path of  a file in the database is ranked by a number of likes. The number of likes for a file can go up and down, and it does so frequently.

Now I have a client who would like to get the first 10 descending ranked files on the first page, and the next
10 ranked files on the second page and so on.

How would I handle the frequent changes  to the rankings of these files, if we want to display the files in  real-time on the client.

Doing a request each time to the database, getting all of the files and then sorting it by likes kind of feels wrong, since the database can possibly get quite large.

I also thought about just having a in-memory cache on the server that stores maybe the first X number of ranked files or even all of them. Would that be better?
Maybe then I could use sockets and for every change in likes of a file I could  just inform the clients about it?

I really don't know how to approach this problem, or  even what is the correct way of doing these kinds of things.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What is a requirement around consistency? 
For example, Let's say, I changed the rating of a file at 10:00AM and now I want to get the content list, should that change be reflected immediately in the list or we can say that change will be reflected within X number of hours?

Comment: It  should change more or less immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution here will be to implement a dedicated counter table. The table will look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE counter_table (
  file_path int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  like_count int(10) signed DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (file_path)
) ENGINE=InnoDB)
```

Note that I have specified the ENGINE as InnoDB as unlike MyISAM which as table level locking, InnoDB implements row level locking. It means that concurrent queries updating different rows in the same table would not block each other, unlike in MyISAM.

Now you can just update the value per file with a query like this.

```
UPDATE counter_table SET like_count = like_count+1 where file_path="XYZ";
```

This solution should serve moderate to high traffic. As you start approaching very high traffic, then you may need to evaluate more stream aggregation based solution like [Apache Spark Streaming](https://sonra.io/2017/11/27/advanced-spark-structured-streaming-aggregations-joins-checkpointing/).